# TypeError (superclass mismatch for class SessionsController)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I do authorization through "login" and because of this there is such an error:

> Started POST "/auth/sign_in" for 10.12.4.5 at 2018-08-07 10:20:55
>   +0500
>
> LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Overrides::SessionsController,
>   expected /home/admin/Рабочий
>   стол/demo/backend/app/controllers/overrides/sessions_controller.rb to
>   define it):
>
> activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:512:in
>   `load_missing_constant' activesupport (5.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:202:in`const_missing'
>   activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:284:in
>   `const_get' activesupport (5.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:284:in`block in constantize'
>   activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in
>   `each' activesupport (5.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in`inject' activesupport
>   (5.1.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
>   activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in`get'
>   activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:614:in
>   `constantize' actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:85:in`controller_class_for'
>   actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:99:in
>   `binary_params_for?' actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:90:in`set_binary_encoding'
>   actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb:67:in
>   `path_parameters=' actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:48:in`block in serve'
>   actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
>   actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in`serve'
>   actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in
>   `call' warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in`block in call'
>   warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch' warden (1.2.7)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in`call' rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in
>   `call' rack (2.0.5) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in`call' rack
>   (2.0.5) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call' activerecord (5.1.6)
>   lib/active_record/migration.rb:556:in`call' actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
>   activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in`
>   run_callbacks' actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call' actionpack
>   (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`call'
>   actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
>   actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in`call'
>   railties (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app' railties
>   (5.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`block in call' activesupport
>   (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
>   activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged' activesupport (5.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged' railties (5.1.6)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`call' actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call' request_store
>   (1.4.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in`call' actionpack
>   (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call' rack
>   (2.0.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in`call' activesupport (5.1.6)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in
>   `call' actionpack (5.1.6)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`call' actionpack
>   (5.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call' rack
>   (2.0.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in`call' rack-cors (1.0.2)
>   lib/rack/cors.rb:97:in `call' railties (5.1.6)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in`call' puma (3.11.4)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call' puma (3.11.4)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:632:in`handle_request' puma (3.11.4)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:446:in `process_client' puma (3.11.4)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:306:in`block in run' puma (3.11.4)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
>
> TypeError (superclass mismatch for class SessionsController):
>
> app/controllers/overrides/sessions_controller.rb:1:in `'

/overrides/sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController

  def resource_data(opts = {})
    opts[:resource_json] || @resource.as_json
  end

  def render_new_error
    render json: {
      errors: [I18n.t("devise_token_auth.sessions.not_supported")]
    }, status: 405
  end

  def render_create_success
    render json: {
      sponsor: resource_data(resource_json: @resource.userable.token_validation_response)
    }
  end

  def render_create_error_not_confirmed
    render json: {
      errors: [I18n.t("devise_token_auth.sessions.not_confirmed", login: @resource.login)]
    }, status: 404
  end

  def render_create_error_bad_credentials
    render json: {
      errors: [I18n.t("devise_token_auth.sessions.bad_credentials")]
    }, status: 402
  end

  def render_destroy_success
    render json: {
    }, status: 200
  end

  def render_destroy_error
    render json: {
      errors: [I18n.t("devise_token_auth.sessions.user_not_found")]
    }, status: 404
  end
```

end

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
    sessions:  'overrides/sessions'
  }
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `class Overrides::SessionsController`? It looks like it should be namespaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error message says what needs to be done:

> Unable to autoload constant Overrides::SessionsController, expected /home/admin/Рабочий стол/demo/backend/app/controllers/overrides/sessions_controller.rb to define it)

`Rails` expects `app/controllers/overrides/sessions_controller.rb` to define `Overrides::SessionsController`, but can't find it.

Change your controller class definition to:

```
class Overrides::SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::ApplicationController
  ...
end
```